# How to disable mobile and desktop scrolling on click

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll, touch

> Hello, everyone. I am dealing with this small mobile menu that uses
>   fadeToggle to show 5 links when a button is clicked. I am using the
>   jquery ui overlay for the overlay effect. What i am trying to achieve
>   here is that when you click the menu it shows the links and disables
>   mobile and desktop scrolling until you press the button again to hide
>   the menu or until you press the overlay effect. I found some ways to
>   disable scrolling in desktop but it doesn't restore the scroll ability
>   after you close the menu. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

```
$("#mmenu").hide();
     $(".ui-overlay").hide();
     $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide();
    $(".navicon").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#mmenu").fadeToggle(300);
        $(".ui-overlay").fadeToggle(300);
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").fadeToggle(300);
    });
    $(".ui-overlay").click(function() {
    $("#mmenu").fadeToggle(300);
    $(".ui-overlay").fadeToggle(300);
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").fadeToggle(300);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at that:

- global var's:

  ```
  scrollTopPos = $( document ).scrollTop();
  allowScrolling = true;
  ```
- when scrolling:

  ```
  $(document).scroll(function() {
      if(allowScrolling === false) {
          $( document ).scrollTop( scrollTopPos );
      } else {

      }
  });
  ```
- disable:

  ```
  scrollTopPos = $( document ).scrollTop();
  allowScrolling = false;
  ```
- enable:

  ```
  allowScrolling = true;
  ```

### demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UbnQ4/11/

Comment: This did disable the scrolling but i want it to re enable it when you click the same button or the overlay to close the menu.

Comment: Thank you! This function works perfect. And i learned something new.